# Trying to allow a user to select a text file using a Scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

As the title says I'm trying to allow a user enter the name of the file they want to select, in order for my program to analyse that text file. 
However when I enter the name of the text file, which is "test.txt" I receive a file not found error, the file is in the same directory as the class which is why I am so confused as to why it doesn't work, could someone help explain what I'm doing wrong here?

This is the code I have:

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
   String filename = in.nextLine();
   File InputFile = new File(filename);

   Scanner reader = new Scanner(InputFile);
```

The Error:

```
Enter filename: test.txt //Here is what I have entered after being prompted.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Thanks!

Comment: trying using the entire file path (l.e. `C:/Users/Me/text.txt`)

Comment: Java often looks for files where you don't expect it to, beware of that.

Comment: The file name is appended to the current working directory, which is the directory you are in when you run the program, not the directory where the class file is.

Comment: No luck, I'm really not sure what else to try, I would use a JFileChooser but I'm a bit unsure of them

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes I know ths

Comment: So, which directory are you in when you run the file? And is the text file in the same directory?

Comment: Explain how you invoke this program, and add a `dir` command from the very same folder in the file system where you run the program, showing that test.txt is indeed in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to deal with the FileNotFoundException**

> 1. **If the message of the exception claims that there is no such file or
>      directory, then you must verify that the specified is correct and
>      actually points to a file or directory that exists in your system.**
> 2. If the message of the exception claims that permission is denied then, you must first check if the permissions of the file are correct
>      and second, if the file is currently being used by another
>      application.
> 3. If the message of the exception claims that the specified file is a
>      directory, then you must either alter the name of the file or delete
>      the existing directory (if the directory is not being used by an
>      application).

**Important:**

> For those developers that use an IDE to implement their Java
>   applications, the relative path for every file must be specified
>   starting from the level where the src directory of the project
>   resides.

Note: Your issue is number option one.

What I do to resolve this issue?

1. I usually use **absolute path** which I do not recommend because it is just Micky Mouse job.
2. Use **relative path** because your program will be path independent.

Answer (score 0):

From java docs:

public Scanner(File source)
        throws FileNotFoundException

Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file. Bytes from the file are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

Parameters:
    source - A file to be scanned
Throws:
    FileNotFoundException - if source is not found

You should just call

```
InputFile.createNewFile();
```

before

```
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(InputFile);
```